# Точка ставится до или после кавычек?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

И все же как правильно в этом случае:

1. Моя совесть сказала: "Стыдно мне не знать русского языка."
2. Моя совесть сказала: "Стыдно мне не знать русского языка".

Правила говорят, что второй вариант правильный. Но мне он глаз режет, ведь точка тоже по сути является интонационной. Просто она говорит о том, что ее (интонации) в предложении нет!

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, что именно вас интересует?

Answer (score 1):

Я вопрос понимаю так. Читаем Розенталя: Вопросительный и восклицательный знаки, а также многоточие ставятся **перед** закрывающими кавычками, а точка — **после них**.

**А почему?**

Чем точка отличается от других знаков, ведь каждый знак соответствует определенной интонации: восклицательной, вопросительной. Точка же обозначает повествовательную интонацию, то есть понижение голоса в конце предложения.

Конечно, это условность, но почему принято такое решение? Может быть, об этом хочет спросить автор вопроса?

Comment: Ссылочку не дадите на Р.? Меня формулировка смущает. Насколько помню, ***восклицательный или вопросительный знак внутри кавычек не освобождает от необходимости ставить точку после них***. Тогда вопрос совершенно не так понимается. Или я что-то путаю?!

Comment: Розенталь § 48. Прямая речь после слов автора.http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=156#pp156

Comment: Да, дела... Хотя формулировка спорная. Вот из сети, пример условный. ***Я сказал: "Удачи!"(.) Она ответила: "Cпасибо!"(.)*** Неужели не поставите даже в первом случае, когда это не конец строки?!

Comment: Г-н @Morkovkin, закон есть закон, хотя не всем он писан.

Comment: У Лопатина то же самое http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138    Еще есть интересный момент: по-разному оформляется прямая речь и цитата в СПП (точка есть или нет после кавычек при наличии многоточия): Искандер заметил, что «мудрость — это ум, настоянный на совести...». Филипп машинально водил рулевым веслом и всё думал: «Марьюшка, Марья...»  То же относится и к другим знакам (восклицательному и вопросительному).

Comment: *У Лопатина то же самое* - не вижу чтоб "то же самое", какой параграф? Но дело даже не в этом. Ни одного примера на этот случай все равно нету, ни у Р., ни у Л.. Поэтому остаётся простор для толкований. *по-разному оформляется прямая речь и цитата в СПП* - вот это и есть еще один аргумент, что с формулировками что-то не так.

Comment: У Лопатина § 134.http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138     Примеры у Розенталя :§119. Прямая речь после авторских слов http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm

Comment: Вы абсолютно правильно поставили вопрос. Почему было принято такое решение? Хотя я с ним не согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Это не "не совсем элементарный", это вообще не вопрос. Ну, глаз режет, ну и что? "Интонационная точка, говорящая, что интонации нет" – что-то новенькое, а главное, заумное.

Answer (score 0):

Точка не интонационный знак. А ставится она один раз за кавычками, потому что иначе её пришлось бы ставить дважды.

Comment: Согласен, но мысль надо развить и пояснить. Ставится один ***раз***?

Comment: Розенталь: Точка ставится в конце законченного ПОВЕСТВОВАТЕЛЬНОГО предложения:http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=87#pp87

Comment: В устной речи повествовательные предложения оформляются особым типом ИНТОНАЦИИ: как правило, они характеризуются понижением основного тона к концу предложения. На письме в конце повествовательного предложения ставится точка или многоточие.  http://iessay.ru/add_materials/lingvisticheskie-terminy-i-opredeleniya/predlozhenie-povestvovatelnoe-utverditelnoe-otricatelnoe

Comment: Я подумаю-------------